# Catch errors caused by evaluate() in CasperJS / PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I'm wondering why the following code isn't picking up errors output in the console by javascript code executed using the evaluate() method.

```
casper.on 'resource.error', ->
    @echo 'Resource error: ' + "Error code: "+resourceError.errorCode+" ErrorString: "+resourceError.errorString+" url: "+resourceError.url+" id: "+resourceError.id, "ERROR"
```

Since evaluate() executes the code in the context of the web browser, shouldn't any errors caused by it be caught by the code above?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure exactly what "resource" means. :/ Are resources things sent to and back by the server and page things that just happen on the browser? If that's the case, is there a way to catch page.error in casperjs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation to 'resource.error'](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#resource-error) says it all:

> Emitted when any requested resource fails to load properly. The received `resourceError` object has the following properties

It has nothing to do with the page errors. In fact [`casper.evaluate()`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#evaluate) and the PhantomJS equivalent [`page.evaluate()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html) don't send requests to the page in order to interact with it. It is all baked into the same engine. The only limitation is that `evaluate()` is sandboxed. It doesn't have access to variables defined outside, so you have to explicitly pass them in and out.

**What you want is the ["page.error" event](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error):**

> Emitted when retrieved page leaves a Javascript error uncaught

---

Take for example the following complete script:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.on("remote.message", function(msg) {
    this.echo("Console: " + msg);
});

casper.on("page.error", function(msg, trace) {
    this.echo("Error: " + msg);
});

casper.on("resource.error", function(msg, trace) {
    this.echo("Res.Error: " + msg);
});

casper.start("http://example.com",function(){
    this.evaluate(function(){
        null.pop();
    });
});

casper.run();
```

It outputs:

```
Error: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'null.pop')
```

Comment: if I wanted to throw a error how would I do that? I've tried
throw new Error(msg) and throw new CasperError(msg), but they don't seem to do anything.

Comment: Weird. echo works fine but when I throw an error, I see nothing in the console log. Throwing an error exits casper right?

Comment: An uncaught error stops the script, but doesn't exit it (I think). An uncaught error on the page or inside `evaluate()` doesn't stops or exit the CasperJS script.

Comment: Hm but by throwing the error in the casper.on('page.error'), it should stop on uncaught error in evaluate()? I'm just confused why it's not doing anything.

Comment: If you wish to stop the script, then you should print some error to the console and call `casper.exit(1)` or some other exit code.

Comment: Oh no, I'm just wondering if my "throw new CasperError()" is working properly. Is that just a feature in mocha-casperjs testing framework? What should I expect from the code throw new Error 'msg' ?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea how mocha-casperjs works. `throw "msg";`, `throw new Error("msg");` and `throw new CasperError("msg");` work similarly, but `CasperError` is an error type that is defined by CasperJS' bootstrap process. I have no idea if it is available in mocha-casperjs.

Comment: I meant I have used the code throw new CasperError() in mocha and it outputs the error in console in error-format. I was wondering if I should be seeing the same thing. I actually just tried putting the throw code later in the code under casper.then -> and it's working as expected. For some reason when it's in the casper.on listener, it does nothing (Although it is getting called)